# Do we want hats (WinterBash 2015)?

Tags: discussion

Winter Bash (**[2014 (promotion page)](http://stackexchange.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014)**, **[2013 (blog post)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)**) is a fun Stack Exchange tradition to celebrate the holidays. Simply put, it's allows users to get "hats" that you can put on your avatar and that are displayed across the network on participating sites.

Speaking of participating sites, Stack Exchange allows each community to opt out as a whole if they have reasons to do so, such as appearing more professional without hats. If you're not a hatter (you're a hater of hats!), **you can manually opt out of seeing hats on all Stack Exchange sites.**

This event will run from **December 14th, 2015 to January 3rd, 2016.**

So let's *hat*ve at it! Do we want hats?

Answer (score 2):

Yes we loved to do!

But, as you know, these hats are static. My opinion is that let's wear well-designed dinamically gif pictures to get these gifts. Not static jpegs, just make these hats can be able to rotate, dance, shining, and/or shaking e.t.c. according to the forums.

For example, if I am in Stack overflow, I want my hat is flowing. And, if I am in Arduino Forum, I want my hat to blink itself with red, white, yellow colors.

These are my opinions to improve your question.